# Rank of homology group

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

$x_0$ is the unique a global minimum and let $c=f(x_0)$ in a Hilbert space, let $\theta$ be an other critical point of $f$ non minimum.

the Morse type number of $x_0$ is

$$m_q(x_0)=R_q(f^{c+\varepsilon}\cap U_{x_0},f^{c-\varepsilon}\cap U_{x_0})=R_q(U_{x_0},\emptyset)=\left\{\begin{array}{lc} 1 & \text{if}\ q=0 \\ 0 & \text{if}\ q\neq 0\end{array}\right. $$

for $\varepsilon >0$ small, where $$R_q(f^{c+\varepsilon}\cap U_{x_0},f^{c-\varepsilon}\cap U_{x_0})$$ is the rank of the relative singuler homology group $$H_q(f^{c+\varepsilon}\cap U_{x_0},f^{c-\varepsilon}\cap U_{x_0}), f^{\alpha}=\{x\in H, f(x)\leq \alpha\}$$

if i assume that there were no other critical points than $\theta$ and $x_0$, then there would be no critical points in $H\setminus f^b$, if $b> \max\{ f(\theta),c\}$

I dont understand why then we have that : $$R_q(f^b)=R_q(H)=\left\{\begin{array}{lc} 1 & \text{if}\ q=0 \\ 0 & \text{if}\ q\neq 0\end{array}\right. $$

in the paper they say that because $f^b$ is a retract deformation of $H$ , but i don't understand why in this case the morse index is equal to zero ????

Please help me

Thank you.